# Binding to a non dependancy property

Tags: wpf

I have a custom control which has non-dependency properties but I want to bind a list to the property. How can this be achieved?

The reason I cannot use dependency properties is because i am generating the data in a different thread to the UI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create data bindings for a regular CLR property. It has to be a `DependencyProperty`.

But you can easily generate your data via background threads in your model or view model for their CLR properties which will be binding targets. You will then need `Dispatcher.Invoke()` or similar method to ensure you assign new property values on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason I cannot use dependency properties is because i am
>   generating the data in a different thread to the UI.

That doesn't make sense. There is nothing stopping you from populating dependency properties with the data from another thread. You need to use async/await or BackgroundWorker (if before 4.5)